# Sum of convergent sequence.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How would I find the sum of this convergent sequence?
I don't believe I can solve it as a geometric series or through the telescoping method.

$$
1 + \ln(2) + \frac{\ln(2)^2}{2!} +\frac{\ln(2)^3}{3!}+ ... + \frac{\ln(2)^n}{n!} + ... 
$$

Comment: Do you know that $e^x = \sum \frac{x^n}{n!}$?

Comment: No, I did not. So the answer is 2?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Thank you! That was very helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Given that:
$$
e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}
$$

It follows that your series converges to $2$.

Answer (score 3):

Given information from Ayman Hourieh:
$$ e^x = \sum \frac{x^n}{n!} $$

Then
$$ 1 + \ln(2) + \frac{\ln(2)^2}{2!} + ... + \frac {\ln(2)^n}{n!} + ... ? $$
is equal to
$$ \sum \frac{\ln(2)^n}{n!} $$
and
$$ e^{\ln 2} = \sum \frac{\ln(2)^n}{n!} = 2$$